# не срабатывает ajax запрос Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Столкнулся с  следующей проблемой:
нужно вытащить из php переменную и передать ее  в js 
Помогите советом, что я не так делаю?
вот пример кода:

PHP:

```
        <?php
         $a = $slider_before_img;
         $arr = array('thumb' => $a);
         echo json_encode($arr);
        ?>
```

JS:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $.getJSON("index.php",
    function(data){
        $("#my-thumb").html(data.thumb);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Из приведённого отрывка непонятно, где находится этот код и пытается ли он использовать в  php части функции и структуры ядра WordPress,темы и плагинов. Если да, то такой код работать не может в принципе, потому что не проведена инициализация ядра.

В WordPress существуют свои правила выполнения ajax-запросов. Подробнее об этом можно почитать на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).